# How to change case of a UTF file

Tags: linux, bash, text

I have a UTF file in uppercase, and I want to change all words to lowercase.

I have tried:

```
`tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input.txt > output.txt`
```

But that changes only characters without an accent.

Comment: Maybe this belongs on SuperUser?

Comment: Sure, mistake, but I have no idea how to move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default character classes only work on standard ASCII, which does not include most of the international accented characters. If you have a defined set of those characters, the easiest way would be to simply add the mapping from special uppercase character to special lowercase character manually:

tr 'ÄÖU[:upper:]' 'äöü[:lower:]'

If you only have a few accented characters, this is workable.

Answer (score 5):

Finally the simplest way I found is to use [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '{print tolower($0)}' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This is, indeed, the "correct" way to go about it, since `awk` is Unicode-aware and `tr` isn't. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, the issue is that `tr` is not Unicode aware.

```
$ grep -o '[[:upper:]]' <<< JalapeÑo
J
Ñ
$ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< JalapeÑo
jalapeÑo
```

The *reason* to use `[:upper:]`, etc., is in order to handle characters outside ASCII. Otherwise, you could just use `[A-Z]` and `[a-z]`. That's also why PCRE has a character class called `[:ascii:]]`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/[[:ascii:]]//g' <<< jalapeño
ñ
```

Comment: You're right! But using character classes never worked for me up to now, neither in unicode nor in latin1, so I gave up on it a long time ago and always do it manually :-(