# How can I convert a string from uppercase to lowercase in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, uppercase, lowercase

I have been searching to find a way to convert a string value from uppercase to lowercase. All the search results show approaches of using the `tr` command.

The problem with the `tr` command is that I am able to get the result only when I use the command with the *[echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)* statement. For example:

```
y="HELLO"
echo $y| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

The above works and results in 'hello', but I need to assign the result to a variable as below:

```
y="HELLO"
val=$y| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
string=$val world
```

When assigning the value like above it gives me an empty result.

PS: My Bash version is 3.1.17

Comment: for files: cat file_name | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' >> lower

Comment: I needed to use `val=$(echo $y | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')` rather than just `val=$y| tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`

Answer (score 248):

If you are using Bash 4, you can use the following approach:

```
x="HELLO"
echo $x  # HELLO

y=${x,,}
echo $y  # hello

z=${y^^}
echo $z  # HELLO
```

Use only one `,` or `^` to make the first letter `lowercase` or `uppercase`.

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. When i tried the above it says ${y,,}--bad substitution. Any how i tried another approach of y="HI" val = $( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $y) and this worked for me.Thanks once again

Comment: Your bash version too low. It doesn't support those features.

Comment: Yes...Am trying to do the same logic in ant build.xml file.Trying to convert a string from uppercase to lowercase.How do I achievce that.Tried scriptdef pattern and others and it dint work..

Comment: bash string substitution doesn't work on centos 5.9

Comment: The ,, ^^ substitutions only work on bash 4, not bash 3 so you'd need to upgrade bash or use the tr approach.

Comment: If bad substitution message is returned, also check if you accidentally wrote '$' before variable name (${$y,,} instead of ${y,,}), which results in the same error as when bash version is too low (you can check it with 'bash --version').

Comment: I was confused for a moment because I was doing `bash --version` and getting 5.0.3, but then realized that was brew version of bash (at `/usr/local/bin/bash`). My script had my system bash in the header with `#!/bin/bash` which was version 3 :(

Comment: bash version 4.4.20(1)-release
`bad substitution`

Comment: version 5.1.12(1)-release in /usr/local/bin/bash (brew) also failing on the CLI with the above error

Comment: [based on this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392189/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-in-bash#comment15018544_11392248), I take this as I should not consider this as a feature of bash for another decade...  Referring to the ["canonical" linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash) of which this Q is a duplicate shows some more time-tested solutions.

Answer (score 91):

One way to implement your code is

```
y="HELLO"
val=$(echo "$y" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
string="$val world"
```

This uses `$(...)` notation to capture the output of the command in a variable. Note also the quotation marks around the `string` variable -- you need them there to indicate that `$val` and `world` are a single thing to be assigned to `string`.

If you have Bash 4.0 or higher, a more efficient & elegant way to do it is to use Bash built-in string manipulation:

```
y="HELLO"
string="${y,,} world"
```

Answer (score 37):

Note that `tr` can only handle plain ASCII, making any `tr`-based solution fail when facing international characters.

Same goes for the Bash 4-based `${x,,}` solution.

The [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) tool, on the other hand, properly supports even UTF-8 / multibyte input.

```
y="HELLO"
val=$(echo "$y" | awk '{print tolower($0)}')
string="$val world"
```

Answer courtesy of [liborw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270937/60281).

Comment: Thanks. Options with `tr` didn't work for me. Might be a MacOS/BSD thing.

Answer (score 26):

Execute in backticks:

```
 x=`echo "$y" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

This assigns the result of the command in backticks to the variable `x`. (I.e., it's not particular to `tr`, but it is a common pattern/solution for shell scripting.)

You can use `$(..)` instead of the backticks. See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. the above works..to make it better i tried                                                                y="HI"                                                               val = $( tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' <<< $y) and it worked fine for me..Thank you once again for your suggestion

Comment: @raga `<<<` - love it!!! much more elegant than `echo` "overkill" ☺︎

Comment: Just remember that `\$`, double backslash and backslash backtick will not be treated literally with backticks, but they will inside `$(..)`.  That could be good or bad depending on your usecase.  http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html Section 3.4.5.

Answer (score 11):

I'm on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr), with Bash version 4.3.11. However, I still don't have the fun built-in string manipulation `${y,,}`

This is what I used in my script to force capitalization:

```
CAPITALIZED=`echo "${y}" | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`
```

Comment: Does the shebang line at the top of your script point to an older version of bash?

Comment: No, I only have one version installed on my system, so it points to the system default bash.

Comment: I think that the `[]` are not required: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/51983/how-to-uppercase-the-command-line-argument#comment801846_344791

Comment: `${y,,}` won't work in Ubuntu if you use `#!/bin/sh` since the default shell is Dash. You must use `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 6):

If you define your variable using declare (old: typeset) then you can state the case of the value throughout the variable's use.

```
declare -u FOO=AbCxxx
echo $FOO
```

Output:

```
ABCXXX
```

Option `-l` to *[declare](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)* does lowercase:

> When the variable is assigned a value, all upper-case characters are converted to lower-case. The upper-case attribute is disabled.

Comment: Not in Bash 3.2

Comment: Bash 3.2 [was released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29#Release_history) on 2006-10-11 (nearly 16 years ago). That was before [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29) was (officially) discovered (2014).

Comment: @Amit Naidu: What system are you using?

Answer (score 5):

[Building on Rody's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392189/how-can-i-convert-a-string-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-in-bash/11392488#11392488), this worked for me.

```
y="HELLO"
val=$(echo $y | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
string="$val world"
```

One small modification: if you are using underscore next to the variable, you need to encapsulate the variable name in {}.

```
string="${val}_world"
```

Comment: Is it only underscore (not a rhetorical question)? What about other punctuation, like comma?