# case insensitive string comparison in bash

Tags: bash, string-comparison

The following line removes the leading text before the variable `$PRECEDING`

```
temp2=${content#$PRECEDING}
```

But now i want the `$PRECEDING` to be case-insensitive. This works with `sed`'s `I` flag. But i can't figure out the whole cmd.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case Insensitive comparision of strings in Shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728683/case-insensitive-comparision-of-strings-in-shell-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
temp2=$(sed -e "s/^.*$PRECEDING//I" <<< "$content")
```

**Explanation:**

- `^.*$PRECEDING`: `^` means start of string, `.` means any character, `.*` means any character zero or more times. So together this means "match any pattern from start of string that is followed by (and including) string stored in `$PRECEDING`.
- The `I` part means case-insensitive, the `g` part (if you use it) means "match all occurrences" instead of just the 1st.
- The `<<<` notation is for [herestrings](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html), so you save an `echo`.

Comment: This deletes only the $PRECEDING variable. with gI it also is case-insensitive!! But how do you also delete the leading text before the $PRECEDING variable?

Comment: @user1898411 see updated answer: (`^.*$PRECEDING` instead of `$PRECEDING`)

Answer (score 9):

No need to call out to sed or use shopt.  The easiest and quickest way to do this (as long as you have Bash 4):

```
if [ "${var1,,}" = "${var2,,}" ]; then
  echo "matched"
fi
```

All you're doing there is converting both strings to lowercase and comparing the results.

Answer (score 1):

The only bash way I can think of is to check if there's a match (case-insensitively) and if yes, exclude the appropriate *number of characters* from the beginning of $content:

```
content=foo_bar_baz
PRECEDING=FOO
shopt -s nocasematch
[[ $content == ${PRECEDING}* ]] && temp2=${content:${#PRECEDING}}
echo $temp2
```

Outputs: `_bar_baz`

Answer (score 1):

your examples have context-switching techniques. 
better is (bash v4):

```
VAR1="HELLoWORLD"
VAR2="hellOwOrld"

if [[ "${VAR1^^}" = "${VAR2^^}" ]]; then
    echo MATCH
fi
```

link: [Converting string from uppercase to lowercase in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392189/converting-string-from-uppercase-to-lowercase-in-bash#11392248)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Bash 4, I find the easiest way is to first convert your string to lowercase using `tr`

```
VAR1=HelloWorld
VAR2=helloworld

VAR1_LOWER=$(echo "$VAR1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
VAR2_LOWER=$(echo "$VAR2" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

if [ "$VAR1_LOWER" = "$VAR2_LOWER" ]; then
  echo "Match"
else
  echo "Invalid"
fi
```

This also makes it really easy to assign your output to variables by changing your echo to `OUTPUT="Match"` & `OUTPUT="Invalid"`